# Can a function f be Riemann integrable over an open interval? Or does the interval considered always need to be closed?

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

When dealing with functions that are Riemann integrable, I've always considered the function over a closed interval
i.e $$f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$$
but I am just wondering if you can have functions like $$f:[a,b)\to\mathbb{R} \text{ or } f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$$ that are Riemann integrable also.

Comment: Consult your definitions. Directly.

Comment: Those are called improper integrals or generalised.

Comment: The definition of Riemann integral is for functions bounded on closed intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $f$ is bounded in $(a,b)$ you can define

$\hat f(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in(a,b)$ and $\hat f(a)=\hat f(b)=0$.

So, if $f$ in Riemann integrable, then $\hat f$ too because $\{a,b\}$ has zero measure. In fact
$$
\int_a^b\hat f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx
$$